# how to use Big SQL commands to automate the synchronization with HIVE through shell script?

Tags: shell, hive, bigsql

I have written a small shell script to automate the Big SQL and HIVE synchronization.
Code is as below

```
echo "Login to BigSql"
<path to>/jsqsh bigsql --user=abc --password=pwd
echo "login succesfull"

echo "Syncing hive table <tbl_name> to Big SQL"
call syshadoop.hcat_sync_objects('DB_name','tbl_name','a','REPLACE','CONTINUE');

echo "Syncing hive table TRAINING_TRACKER to Big SQL Successfully"
```

Unfortunately, I am getting the message:

```
Login to BigSql
Welcome to JSqsh 4.8
Type "\help" for help topics. Using JLine.
```

And then it enters the Big SQL command prompt. Now when I type "quit" and hit enter, it gives me following messages:

```
login succesful
    Syncing hive table <tbl_name> to Big SQL
    ./script.sh: line 10: call syshadoop.hcat_sync_objects(DB_name,tbl_name,a,REPLACE,CONTINUE): command not found
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to redirect the output of your later commands into the `jsqsh` command. E.g. see this example

> You can start JSqsh and run the script at the same time with this command:
>
> ```
> /usr/ibmpacks/common-utils/current/jsqsh/bin/jsqsh bigsql < /home/bigsql/mySQL.sql
> ```

from here https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSCRJT_5.0.2/com.ibm.swg.im.bigsql.doc/doc/bsql_jsqsh.html

Answer (score 0):

There already is an auto-hcat sync job in Big SQL that does exactly what you're trying to do

Check if the job is running by

```
su - bigsql (or whatever instance owner)

db2 connect to bigsql 

db2 "select NAME, BEGIN_TIME, END_TIME, INVOCATION, STATUS from 
SYSTOOLS.ADMIN_TASK_STATUS where BEGIN_TIME > (CURRENT TIMESTAMP - 60 minutes) 
and name ='Synchronise MetaData Changes from Hive' "
```

if you don't see an output , simply enable it through Ambari :

[Enable Automatic Metadata Sync](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4T8Y.png)